# Can not connect a Jenkins node with "channel is already closed"

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to connect a node in Jenkins.
The node connects briefly but then disconnects immediately afterward.
Retrying doesn't change the outcome.

How can I resolve this?
Below is the console output obtained at that time.

```
Dec 28, 2023 1:35:14 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status 
INFO: Connected 
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.service.EnvInjectMasterEnvVarsSetter to field java.lang.reflect.Field.modifiers 
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.service.EnvInjectMasterEnvVarsSetter 
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release 
Dec 28, 2023 1:35:14 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status 
INFO: Terminated 
Dec 28, 2023 1:35:14 PM hudson.remoting.Request$2 run 
INFO: Failed to send back a reply to the request UserRequest:jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller$FindEffectiveRestarters@10d6b220: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@17ed0a9b:JNLP4-connect connection to XXX.com/00.00.00.00:PORT": channel is already closed
```

use Jenkins 2.426.1, macOS 12.1, openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20